# What is C++/CLI version of [Editor(typeof(FolderNameEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor))]?

Tags: c++, c++-cli, propertygrid

This is an embarrassing question but I feel like I tried everything for last couple of hours.

I just want to add attribute of following to my property

```
 #using <System.Drawing.dll>
 #using <System.Design.dll>
 ...
 using namespace System::Drawing::Design;
 using namespace System::Configuration;
 using namespace System::ComponentModel;
 using namespace System::Windows::Forms::Design;
 ...

[Editor(typeof(FolderNameEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor))]
 property System::String^           DefaultWorkingDirectory;
```

First, I tried as it is and compiler says "illegal use of the type (FolderNameEditor).

Now I tried this

```
    [Editor(Type::GetType("System.Windows.Form.Design.FolderNameEditor, System.Design, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"), 
        Type::GetType("System.Drawing.Design.UITypeEditor, System.Drawing, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"))]
```

But it says illegal attribute argument.

If I do following, the C++/CLI project compiles

```
    [Editor("System.Windows.Form.Design.FolderNameEditor", "System.Drawing.Design.UITypeEditor")]
```

But Whenever I tried to get reference of the project from a C# project, I get an error saying the namespace is missing. If I comment out the editor attribute and #using and using namespace above, everything is just fine.

For some reason, I can't find related materials in MSDN, if you can point out proper document, that would be appreciated.

**UPDATE:** The C# project was .NET 4 Client Profile and that's the reason why I got the error indicating missing namespace which is misleading. Changing the target framework to .NET 4 solved the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The C++/CLI equivalent to `typeof()` is `::typeid`. Try this:

```
[Editor(FolderNameEditor::typeid, UITypeEditor::typeid)]
```